# How to modify the supply voltage requirement in a circuit?

Tags: power-supply, voltage, circuit-analysis, circuit-design, basic

I am a beginner in Electronics; I am learning the basics and am trying to take up circuitry as a hobby! My query is regarding power supply requirement for any circuit.

Take, for example, a circuit to light an LED. I can tell the supply voltage by knowing the LED's Forward Voltage Drop, its maximum current rating, and the resistor in the circuit. By choosing a different valued resistor (or a different LED, perhaps), I can choose a different supply voltage.

Now consider [this](https://www.instructables.com/How-to-Make-FM-Transmitter) circuit. What changes needs to be made to use a different supply voltage? More specifically:

- Is it only resistors which matter?
- How to know which resistors to change out to use a different supply voltage and which ones to leave alone?

On that note, how come some circuits have a fixed supply voltage while others have flexible ones (see [this](https://www.instructables.com/Easy-and-low-cost-FM-transmitter-DIY-kit))? I know that I can't light an LED with anything between 1.5V and 9V without making any changes to the circuit!

---

I am not asking about voltage converters/regulators; see the LED lighting example above.

---

I have been stuck on this for quite some time now, reading articles and tutorials, but I can't seem to find anything which answers my query. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Just something to think about, but if you look at any circuit, *every* component of the circuit has its own voltage, current and power limitations, as well as others.  This means you have to look at the function and use case for every component in the circuit.  You not only have to examine the changes in component values necessary for the circuit to continue to function as intended, but you have to examine how this change in function will affect the load on each component and whether it is up to the new task.  You can't use a 16V capacitor at 24V or a 1/4W resistor at 1W for simple examples.

Comment: For an example simpler than the radio you're asking about, look at the Wikipedia page for a simple buck converter.  If you want to change the output voltage, you may need to upgrade the output capacitor, but other wise it's likely possible with minimal modification to control or feedback.  If you want to change the input voltage, you have to look at a totally different set of components and parameters.  To do this properly, you have to understand how the circuit works and use most of the same skills you would need to design the original component.

Comment: Oh, cool as. I made a couple of those little radios back in about 1986 or 87. When I made them, there was one known as the Earwig and another as the Wasp. The one I made ran off 2x N sized cell, which made the whole thing small enough to fit inside a matchbox with a piece of cardbaord having a few matches glued to it to cover the electronics. I was a little kid at the time. I plugged the battery in and turned it on. Dad made it all, including the board made from fiber material intended for gaskets.I probably wanted to go from 3v to 9v - didn't happen. Easier to find the right circuit..

Comment: For a circuit you do understand or designed the original of, you would know which components were most a factor in the absolute maximum and continuous maximum ratings of the device, so the kind of shortcuts you're asking about kind of do exist, but at a higher skill level than you're looking for, as each shortcut is born of knowledge specific to the application and components.  A good exercise would be to look at a feedback voltage divider feeding an op amp in a voltage converter and examine how the divider needs to change in order to still function when you change input voltage range.

Comment: I guess you’re asking how to go about it rather than just being given a solution.  You’ll need to understand the function of each component in the circuit, it’s voltages, current an power, and then you’ll be able to see what the effect of changing the supply voltage will be, or what range can be tolerated.  Divide and conquer.

Comment: Thank you for all the tips here. This means that, unlike in the LED lighting circuit, it's not only the resistors, but also the capacitors and transistors which determine the supply voltage in the FM transmitter circuit. Did I understand it right?

Answer (score 1):

I would not trust this Mickey Mouse Design to work at any voltage unless tweaked with skill. The schematic won't work.

L1 must be connected to the Antenna to pull up the collector.

R6/R5 ratio must be increased to biased Ve to 35 mV so Vc is half the Vbat.
C4=10pF won't pass any audio.

This design looks like where's Waldo , can you count all the design errors?

Maybe it was corrected in the layout of the pCB

I suggest you look for a better design.  Does it work for you at 9V?

[image]

Looks like they tried to copy the other design and failed miserably swapping parts and misplacing others.

Comment: Both these circuits came from your link

Answer (score 1):

[image]

[Thus clever little circuit](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgDCCsB0Z-CEEYCmBaJSRNgZiQEwGQAckYSuxA7AGy0gAsk2LkuU6mAUAO4i4SjECQiM4IiGG4BzJgE4GBEiQUMqU8NwBKA2qtECCEQ5vEgC0XLUS24HTWGiRuAeSjyC2OiFqQlYKpS3ABOahbmjIoWKuAWxtIALkwSSJ7haV4QWGiWJLSMQtTy1MyMxGBeaE4EmEiM9MqMuOK0WAkgACYoAGYAhgCuADaJfOHKqoyFMUFjUQyG4ibZ3AAOUFMREH5K5ljC0mFL2OnHpvHw3ADGG8IE5pCbSD7ZXDmWfrjUFC1tgVOUcCwChzCTGSapdIEMaQdLPBiPYTwrQ3Y7glIQCZxWjQEhcKTQKb5Yj5Pwke5geRgFhOOBIa63SSM5EQXBvEDVaDyZqQXnFeq4SltBi0kFDDxeQywrwskToVSc6lgXDyeRIMB%20eTkTBwFz8RHeBjzQ1afjGqWbUwwy0QaVM6Rm6IUxnOh3jQLjcy4UICIRM6wGTT0m4G52h2Ks9lOTXUaj3LUUArfLCi%20n6zZY41Yt1EmYYvPSAAeAnITGoTHqUDE2C8ACM%20olEigQgBPAA6AGcAKIAZW03GL1BIWDSwnkJHLaXLd2EAEFOgArAYdxKdgBq9dXHc7bYAjnuAHxH7jGaeQrwBk5eYQAWQAlldO3eAHarAZbpxINedgC2fULnazgAwp2QEAPYDKsQwoJ0awSia3xIj4%20xaGBAhMHEPJIjgVKEJ4KgqlMlJBMCFBxPSaGYBhYjsLUQLwCmwLgnAhTDvcmCCiKFjYFg3poQQ06YbRWSElEypIMOgS4IKQ70XScReAJAjcGhwgHDWBBqtgsBxtQ5AkiUtB6W0clgIUdCUHp4iiC0XwKRh3qCNx2QgPIIBrmBIx9DIKDcEAA) is fairly stable over a wide range of voltages as a toy FM transmitter.

R2C3 act as a sawtooth ramp generator but the frequency is controlled by the high Q resonator tunes by L1 C4 with D5,C7 and to some degree C6 and the antenna.

So a tiny sawtooth generator only 2mV-pp occurs on the base with the Colpitts Oscillator getting pumped by the emitter-collector current pulses.

Due to C ratios in the oscillator the emitter generates about Vcc/2 in Vpp AC near 100 MHz while the collector tied to Vcc with the coil produces 2x Vcc in Vpp AC (doubler) just by ringing when it gets pulled down by the collector. Which occurs whenever Vbe exceeds 600mV which is just the peak of the sinewave. As it switches on, the collector pulls a few milliamps for < 1% of the sinewave and along with it the base voltage to turn it off again. So this is a very stable LC-tuned Relaxation oscillator.  The audio then modulates this base voltage to change the current and shift the frequency ever so slightly 75kHz/100MHz max.
Analog circuits depend on voltage or current references and better ones are regulated by precision resistor ratios with feedback so that over a range of supply voltages, they are stable. Others are optimized over a narrow range for efficiency and must have low noise well-regulated linear supplies.  To change the voltage often is just changing resistor ratios to keep the same base bias voltage which results in emitter/collector current limiting as above.

<s>Thus above one could reduce the voltage in half by reducing the base pull-up R2  to keep Vb constant so that Re = R3 keeps the same DC current.</s>

Comment: Could you explain why only R2 acts as the "load balancer", and not any other component? How do I know that it's only R2? :-)

Comment: I had to simulate it to understand more then I noticed it says 3V~9V so it works pretty well over this range without any changes.

Answer (score 0):

tl; dr: Either your power supply is what the board needs, or the board need to take that down to what *it* needs.

Your example FM transmitter circuit is designed for 9V battery, a common voltage for transistor radios. As far as how *exact* that 9V voltage needs to be depends on the specifics of the design. A good design could tolerate a wide range (especially if it's running on a battery), a bad one would be very sensitive. If it's the latter, go look for a better design, or add a voltage regulator.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the wonderful world of electronics. It's a very rewarding hobby. Don't get discouraged if you're a little confused at times. We've all been there.

For some circuits, it's pretty easy to recalculate a few voltage drops and be done. For more complicated circuits it's, well, more complicated.

Let's just start with your LED example. If you have a circuit that has an LED (let's say it's blue) with a 3.1 Vf and a 5 V power supply. And let's say it has a 190 Ohm resistor to limit the current to 10 mA. Then let's say you want to power this LED in a car that's running 13.2 V (I know they call it 12 V, but for calculations you should use the actual battery voltage or even the charge voltage of the battery) then you would subtract the Vf from the supply voltage and use the remaining voltage in your V/I formula to get the new resistance. 10.1/0.01=1010. So a 1K resistor gets you pretty close to where you need to be to have the same brightness as when you were powered by 5 volts.

Now let's say you want to power that radio circuit with a car instead of a 9 volt battery. Now there are many more things to consider. If we start at the input, the first thing we run into is R7 which is likely intended to apply a voltage to an electret microphone on the input. You probably would not need to change that but you would want to verify that the microphone that you choose would operate with the full VCC applied to it (there are some that only tolerate up to 10V that would not work in this case). Next is a capacitor that provides DC blocking between the input and the base bias on Q1. The value of this probably doesn't need to change since it's mostly frequency dependent and you won't be changing that, but you should make sure that the working voltage exceeds the applied voltage (I like to go at least 50% higher but there are some reasons to go higher or lower in special cases). R5 and R6 bring us to a complicated spot. They are setting the bias on Q1 and that is important for proper operation. In the presented circuit, they are a 1:10 ratio which would imply that the bias voltage is 818 mV, but it actually is not. Now we start getting into the parts where you need to understand more about how transistors work. But let's just say for now that the transistor is going to let as much current through the base as it can until it gets down to about 0.7 V. If you calculate with that bias voltage, you'll get 8.3 volts on R6 when powered with 9 volts and 12.5 V if you power with the car battery. So if you want to maintain the same base current, you might want to change R6 to a 1.5 Megohm resistor.

So, you continue through the circuit until you reach the end or you just throw it on a breadboard and see what smokes... Just kidding, do the calculations, it's actually much more satisfying that way (devil on shoulder disagrees).

Keep in mind that some ICs have a narrow operating range and you should use a properly sized regulator if you want to power them with higher voltages or a boost converter to power them with lower voltage.

Best of luck on your circuit exploration.

Comment: Great explanation, friend! It was getting too overwhelming! :-)